# Processing: How can i make a function wait before running the next line?

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to create a program that shows notes to the user and a few seconds later they get a haptic feedback through a buzzer that they need to hit that note soon. The buzzer is connected through arduino. At the moment, the buzzer buzzes when the note first appears in the screen. I am trying to find a way to make the buzzer work some milliseconds later to be closer to the time they actually need to hit the note. Using a timer with millis() or delay() wont work as I need it to.

```
void readNotes(){
   int i = notesLineIndex;
   if(notesLineIndex < notes.length) {
      notesLineIndex++;
    }
   else return;
   notesLine= notes[i];    
   String[] list = split(notesLine, ',');

   if (Integer.parseInt(list[0]) == 1) el1 = 0;
   if (Integer.parseInt(list[1]) == 1) el2 = 0;
   if (Integer.parseInt(list[2]) == 1) el3 = 0;

   //add delay 
   notesBuzz= notes[i];    
   myPort.write('a'); //create a starting point for array
   myPort.write(list[0]);
   myPort.write(list[1]);
   myPort.write(list[2]);
 }
```

Comment: which language are you using, c# ?

Comment: processing uses java

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Why exactly won't the `millis()` function work for you? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

Note-location: if the notes move horizontally across the screen, you could implement a trigger based on the x-location of the note. Probably the easiest option. If vertical, use the y-location.

Millis(): When the note first appears, store the millis() for that note in a variable. Then on each frame, check if the difference between the stored value and current millis() is larger than the desired delay-time. If so, activate the buzzer.

A note on the delay() function: there are very few cases where it should be used other than prototyping/testing. This is because delay() completely stops the program execution.

Comment: I used the note location and worked! thank you so much, I was so into finding a delay that I didn't think of a workaround

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [delay](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/delay/) function.

```
delay(1000) //wait for 1 second
```

Comment: I can't use delay as it stops the GUI and the notes stop moving